# Invalid Login for Fabric plugin Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am probably doing something wrong, but I have installed the Fabric plugin (2.2.1) into my Eclipse (Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)).The fabric icon is there, but when I enter my user name/password (which work to login into the Fabric site) I get "invalid login". Do I need to do something on the Fabric site first? I am trying to test out Crashlytics on Android, but don't I have to be able to login first?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I ran into a Crashlytics bug. I had done nothing wrong. The support team at Crashlytics were very helpful, but I never actually found out what was wrong on their side. I suspect it had to do with somehow signing up outside the welcome email and then confirming (It was in my trash folder).